# operating system information from a microsoft sql server instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know how to get the operating system information from a microsoft sql server instance via sql?

Using [SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) can get some information but I need to get the operating system e.g. 'Microsoft Windows NT 5.2 (3790)'

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract from @@VERSION

Eg:

```
PRINT @@VERSION
```

Another way is to build a CLR Function or Stored Procedure. Here is a sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString Function1()
    {
        return new SqlString(System.Environment.OSVersion.ToString());
    }
};
```

This example should output this:

```
SELECT dbo.Function1()

Microsoft Windows NT 6.0.6001 Service Pack 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used something like this before:

exec master..xp_cmdshell 'systeminfo'

Comment: You'd hope xp_cmdshell is disabled on a production server.

Comment: Yes definitely I just recall doing it once.